# Hide site-title and site-description wordpress on IE9 and lower

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, hide

I want to hide the site-title and site-description on IE9 and lower. I've hidden them via the appearance option, so its hidden on Chrome, Firefox, IE10+, but it still appear on IE9 and lower.

I've tried to add all this css, but I can not manage to make it work:

```
.site-description {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
h2 .site-description {
    font-size: 10pt;
    display:none !important;
}
#title_subtitle{
display:none !important;
}
#site-title a, #site-description a {visibility:hidden !important;} 
.site-title a, .site-description a {visibility:hidden !important;}
```

I've also tried to delete them in the header, but doesn't work:

the part of the header is:

```
<div id="masterheader"><header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <a class="home-link"<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
          <div id="logo_and_title">
            <img class="header-logo" src="http://thibaultrolando.com/vinacotheque/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo.png"/>
            <div id="title_subtitle">
                <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </div>
```

I'm currently working with a child-theme of twenty-thirteen. I've tried to do this in the `style.css` and also `ie.css` from my child, and also the original theme, but it doesn't seem to work ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide them via php, you should be able to remove them from your theme's `header.php` file. Try commenting out the lines that generate the text. If that does the trick, you can delete them.

```
<div id="title_subtitle">
     <!--
        <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
     -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both, commenting and deleting . . . they're still appearing . . . :s

Comment: Did you try it in both the child and parent?

Comment: yes, in both header from the child and original . .. :s

Comment: Then you've got to look somewhere else.